# Memv procedure in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define memv2
   (lambda (x l)
    (cond
     ((null? l) #f)
     ((eqv? (car l) x) 
        cdr l)
      (else
        (memv2 x (cdr l))))
```

Studying for an exam - this code has been provided in my notes as a replication of the built in memv function in Scheme. I was wondering if someone could explain what the #f is doing in this situation. Is it exiting the loop?

(memv takes in an element and a list, and returns the list from the point of the element onward, for example: (memv 2 '(1 2 3 4 5)) would return (2 3 4 5))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#f` value is returned when the procedure finishes traversing the list, which means that the searched element was not found, thus ending the recursion.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was something along those lines but wanted to make sure. Appreciate it!